# SML: define an array

Tags: sml, smlnj

Forgive me, if it's trivial but
I am reading the documentation of arrays in SML and I am confused . I see many functions but how do I make my own array; How do I initialize one? (Everything , I tried failed)
For example a list is initialised like that :

```
 val l = [1,2,3];
```

if I wanted [1,2,3] to be an array 1x3 ?
I found how to initialize one array but with only one value like:

```
array(4,0) (*creates [0,0,0,0] *)
```

but what about the [1,2,3];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have (at least) two possibilities for that, either using
`Array.fromList`:

```ml
val a = Array.fromList [1, 2, 3];
```

either using `Array.tabulate`:

```ml
fun incr x = x + 1;
val a = Array.tabulate (3, incr);
```

`Array.tabulate` takes two arguments: the size of your array and a
function used to initialise the items of your array.

```ml
val a = Array.tabulate (3, incr);
```

is thus equivalent to:

```ml
val a = Array.fromList [incr(0), incr(1), incr(2)];
```

Note that I have defined a function `incr` but I could also have done:

```ml
val a = Array.tabulate (3, fn x => x + 1);
```